# Shortest path between three points

Tags: graph, shortest-path, network-flow

In a graph I need to find a shortest path between two points and on the way visit one checkpoint. Also, I can visit each vertex only once. I suppose it have something to do with network flow but I have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: Sorry I cannot give you more, just this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm, here you can found example of implementation.

Comment: thank you, but there is nothing about checkpoint, if I find shortest path between start and checkpoint first, it may block my way to end

Comment: try a google search for "traveling salesman problem"  this is a classic problem.

Comment: so I run TSP on the whole graph, then I know which part is going from start to checkpoint and which from checkpoint to end. And then I run BFS on each part to optimize it?

Comment: It is possible to create a graph where it is not possible to find path you described. Graphs with vertex cut 1, where start and end are on one side of cut, and checkpoint on other side. E.g. tree has that property.

Comment: I still have no idea how to find that path if it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model it entirely as a capacitated multicommodity minimum cost flow problem. You want to go from A to B via C without using a vertex twice. You can model it as a flow from A to C (commodity 1) and a flow from B to C (commodity 2). To avoid a node being used twice, you have to perform the following trick on all your nodes (in your model):

Given a node X with p incoming and t outgoing edges, you create a new node Y and rewire the links. The p incoming links will all arrive in X, the q outgoing edges will all depart from Y. Add only 1 link (L) from X to Y. By setting the capacity of the L-link to 1, each node will only be used once.

You can then write it down as an (M)ILP and have it solved. The ILP will give you the correct solution if it exists. Depending on your application, it might be overkill. If you want a fast heuristic, just use 2 A* searches and hope they don't overlap.